# Syntax error with Glpk: MathProg model processing error

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, ampl, glpk, mathprog

This is my model:

```
set linhas;
set colunas;
param c{j in colunas};
param A{i in linhas,j in colunas};
param b{i in linhas};

var x{j in colunas}>=0;

minimize FO:
   sum{j in colunas} c[j]*x[j];

s.t. R{i in linhas}:
   sum{j in colunas} A[i,j] = b[i];

end;
```

I got the following error when solving the model with `glpsol`:

```
Arquivo1.txt:3: syntax error in parameter data block
Context:  set linhas ; set colunas ; param c {
MathProg model processing error.
```

Can you help me? I could not find what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Can you post what you have in 'Arquivo1.txt' file?

Comment: are your rows/constraints missing `x` variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred because you provided to the solver a model file also as a data file, i.e., you invoked `glpsol` using the following command-line:

```
glpsol -m Arquivo1.txt -d Arquivo1.txt
```

In order to solve the syntax error you need to provide a data file, e.g. `Arquivo1.dat`, to the option `-d` that is different from your model . In the data file you must provide concrete data to your sets `colunas` and `linhas`, as well as to your parameters `a`, `b`, and `c`. Once you have a data file, you can run:

```
glpsol -m Arquivo1.txt -d Arquivo1.dat -o solution.sol
```

Last but not least, enjoy the solution provided in `solution.sol`.

Comment: Hi @MarOli if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Done. Thanks! @Arton Dorneles